# how to send notification if the user is connected my open wifi network in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to send a prompt (notification) to an iPhone device which is connected to my open wifi network?

What is the correct approach to achieve this?

Comment: As in an app? PushNotification? what are you talking about. Because if you want to send a message to devices connected to Wifi network without any app then I have to disappoint you, that will not be possible.

Comment: I mean, once the user connected to my open wifi network, then my backend app automatically detect the device that which iPhone device is connected my network.

Comment: I still don't get it, are you talk about building an iOS app to do this or just just the WiFi network?

Comment: I think op is asking how to push a notification to ANY random iOS device connected to their network.  This just not possible.  Consider how much it would be abused.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an APN server, and push those notifications through Apple's notification gateways.

You can make your own or use a SaaS like `urban airship`.

Alternatively, make a server on your computer and connect to it from the iPhone. Use websockets, when an event happens on the server make a local notification on the iPhone.

Local notifications are allowed on iOS but you might have trouble keeping the websocket connection to your server when the app is in the background.